# I don't know how to use Dio package in new update (last update i used perfectly)

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I don't know how to use Dio package in new update (last update I used perfectly)
this is my old code (it is work in old version of Dio)

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

abstract class Failure {
  final String message;

  Failure({required this.message});
}

class ServerFailure extends Failure {
  ServerFailure({required super.message});
  factory ServerFailure.fromDioException(DioException e) {
    switch (e) {
      case DioException.connectionError:
        return ServerFailure(message: 'connectionError Error');
      case DioException.connectionTimeout:
        return ServerFailure(message: 'connectionTimeout Error');
      case DioException.receiveTimeout:
        return ServerFailure(message: 'receiveTimeout Error');
      case DioException.sendTimeout:
        return ServerFailure(message: 'sendTimeout Error');
      case DioException.badResponse:
        return ServerFailure.formResponse(
            e.response!.statusCode!, e.response!.data!);
      case DioException.requestCancelled:
        return ServerFailure(message: 'requestCancelled Exception');
      default:
        return ServerFailure(message: 'defualt Error');
    }
  }
  factory ServerFailure.formResponse(int statusCode, dynamic response) {
    if (statusCode == 500) {
      return ServerFailure(message: 'there is problem with server');
    } else if (statusCode == 404) {
      return ServerFailure(message: 'your Request was not found');
    } else if (statusCode == 400 || statusCode == 401 || statusCode == 403) {
      return ServerFailure(
          message: 'Bad Requset $statusCode your response is:$response ');
    } else {
      return ServerFailure(message: 'unknown Error');
    }
  }
}
```

The DioException show error to me:

[image: DioException error]

I expected the Dio package make some change

Comment: The switch case expression type 'DioException Function({required String reason, required RequestOptions requestOptions})' must be a subtype of the switch expression type 'DioExceptionType'

Comment: DioException DioException.connectionError({required RequestOptions requestOptions, required String reason})
package:dio/src/dio_exception.dart

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
   
 class DioResponse {
    
      static Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getApi(String api) async {
        Dio dio = new Dio();
        dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
        dio.options.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
        if (Constant.token != "") dio.options.headers["Authorization"] = 'token ${Constant.token}';

  // dio.options.headers["Authorization"] = 'Bearer ${Constant.token}';

        try {
          log(Constant.token);
          final response = await dio.get(api);
          return response.data;
        } on DioError catch (error) {
          if (error.response != null && error.response!.statusCode == 401) {}
          return error.response?.data;
        }
      }
    
      static Future<Response<dynamic>?> postApi(String api, dynamic data) async {
        Dio dio = new Dio();
        dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
        dio.options.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
        if (Constant.token != "") dio.options.headers['Authorization'] = 'token ${Constant.token}';
        try {
          if (Constant.token != "") log(Constant.token);
          final response = await dio.post(api, data: data);
          return response;
        } on DioError catch (error) {
          if (error.response != null && error.response!.statusCode == 401) {}
          return error.response;
        }
      }
    
      static Future<Response<dynamic>?> notificationSwitchApi(String api, dynamic data) async {
    
    
        Dio dio = new Dio();
        dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
        dio.options.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
        if (Constant.token != "") {
          if(Constant.notificationToken == '' || Constant.notificationToken == null || Constant.notificationToken == 'null'){
            dio.options.headers['Authorization'] = 'token ${Constant.token}';
          }else{
            dio.options.headers['Authorization'] = 'token ${Constant.notificationToken}';
          }
        }
    
    
        try {
          if (Constant.token != "") log(Constant.token);
          final response = await dio.post(api, data: data);
          return response;
        } on DioError catch (error) {
          if (error.response != null && error.response!.statusCode == 401) {}
          return error.response;
        }
      }
    
      static Future<Response<dynamic>?> putApi(String api, dynamic data) async {
        Dio dio = new Dio();
        dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
        dio.options.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
        if (Constant.token != "") dio.options.headers['Authorization'] = 'token ${Constant.token}';
        try {
          final response = await dio.put(api, data: data);
          return response;
        } on DioError catch (error) {
          if (error.response != null && error.response!.statusCode == 401) {}
          return error.response;
        }
      }
    
      static Future<Response<dynamic>?> deleteApi(String api) async {
        print(api);
        Dio dio = new Dio();
        dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
        dio.options.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
        if (Constant.token != "") dio.options.headers['Authorization'] = 'token ${Constant.token}';
        try {
          final response = await dio.delete(api);
          return response;
        } on DioError catch (error) {
          if (error.response != null && error.response!.statusCode == 401) {}
          return error.response;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
 Future<void> login(context, {from, queryParameters}) async {
    Constant.fcmToken =
        await SharedPreference.getStringValuesSF(SharedPreference.fcmtoken);

    var jsonData = {
      'email': emailcontroller.value.text.toString().trim(),
      'password': passwordcontroller.value.text.toString().trim(),
      'device_id': await Utils.getDeviceDetails(),
      'fcm': Constant.fcmToken,
    };

    try {
      final response = await DioResponse.postApi(
          ApiSheet.baseUrl + ApiSheet.login, jsonData);
      hideLoadingDialog(context: context);
      logindata logindata11 = logindata.fromJson(response!.data);


      if (logindata11.status!) {
        Constant.token = logindata11.token!;
        SharedPreferences.getInstance().then(
          (prefs) {
            prefs.setBool('remember_me', isChecked);
            prefs.setString(
                'email', emailcontroller.value.text.toString().trim());
            prefs.setString(
                'password', passwordcontroller.value.text.toString().trim());
          },
        );
        }
      
    } on DioError catch (e) {}
  }



  late Rx<RemoveAccountModel> removeacc = RemoveAccountModel().obs;

      showLoadingDialog(context: context, indicatorColor: Utils.primaryColor);

void removerAccount(BuildContext context) async {
    final response = await DioResponse.getApi(
        ApiSheet.baseUrl + Constant.liveUserRoot + ApiSheet.removeAccount);
    hideLoadingDialog(context: context);

    removeacc.value = RemoveAccountModel.fromJson(response);
    if(sic.showSnackBarstatus==true){
          Get.back();
        }
    if (removeacc.value.status!) {
      Get.offAll(SignInActivity());
      showSnackBar('', removeacc.value.message!);
    } else {
      Get.back();
      showSnackBar(removeacc.value.message!, 'You can\'t remove your account.');
    }
  }
```

SignInController sic = Get.put(SignInController());

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: But, also: What’s the difference between this and your other answer? Why did you post two answers? Which should the author, nevertheless future readers, follow? Altogether this is confusing.

Answer (score -1):

```
final e = DioException(requestOptions: RequestOptions());

final type = e.type;

///
/// You must be able to handle all these cases, otherwise you will get a error. 
///
switch (type) {
  case DioExceptionType.unknown:
    throw Exception('DIO other Error: $e');
  case DioExceptionType.receiveTimeout:
    throw Exception('DIO other Error: $e');
  case DioExceptionType.connectionTimeout:
    throw Exception('DIO connectTimeout Error: $e');
  case DioExceptionType.sendTimeout:
    throw Exception('DIO sendTimeout Error: $e');
  case DioExceptionType.cancel:
    throw Exception('DIO cancel Error: $e');
  case DioExceptionType.badCertificate:
    throw Exception('DIO badCertificate Error: $e');
  case DioExceptionType.badResponse:
    throw Exception('DIO badResponse Error: $e');
  case DioExceptionType.connectionError:
    throw Exception('DIO connectionError Error: $e');
}
```

> This image from dio_exception.dart

[image]